# SQL Server CE - IMAGE column

Tags: delphi, sql-server-ce, ado

I know that `IMAGE` datatype is deprecated since a while, but for my project I don't have the choice.

The question is: can I have several IMAGE columns in a table in SQL Server CE?

Because when I make an insert (ADO in Delphi) with more than 1 `IMAGE` column, my program hangs when I call `ExecSQL()`.

With just one IMAGE column, it works:

```
HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear();

HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add( 'INSERT INTO ' + CONFIG_Table_Name + ' SET ' +
        CONFIG_Table[ aCONFIG_PARAM ]      + '=' +  ':param_blob'; + '       ;' );
                         HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('param_blob').LoadFromStream(   Mstream1, ftBlob );
HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL();
```

But with more than one IMAGE column:

```
HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear();

HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add( 'INSERT INTO ' + CONFIG_Table_Name + ' SET ' +
        CONFIG_Table[ aCONFIG_PARAM ]  + '=' +  ':param_blob', + 
        CONFIG_Table[ aCONFIG_SCHEDULES ]  + '=' +  ':schedules_blob'; + '
 ;' );

HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('param_blob').LoadFromStream(     Mstream1, ftBlob );

HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('schedules_blob').LoadFromStream(     Mstream2, ftBlob );

HSLmySQL.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL(); // => Boom, no exceptions catch nothing ..
```

and my program hangs.